# NamedTemporaryFile cannot be acessed from command line

Tags: python, linux, unix

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
with NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    f.write(zip_data)
    f.flush()
    subprocess.call("/usr/bin/7z x %s" % f.name)
```

It dies with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decrypt_resource.py", line 70, in <module>
    unpack(sys.argv[2])
  File "decrypt_resource.py", line 28, in unpack
    print(subprocess.check_output(cmd))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However, if I use `NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)` and then print & execute the command, it works. What's wrong here?

My System is an ArchLinux with a `3.9.5-1-ARCH` kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `subprocess.call()` incorrectly.

Pass in a list of arguments:

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/7z", "x", f.name])
```

The argument is *not* handled by a shell and is not parsed out like a shell would do. This is a good thing as it prevents a security problem with untrusted command line arguments.

Your other options include using [`shlex.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to do the whitespace splitting for you, or, as a last resort, telling `subprocess` to use a shell for your command with the `shell=True` flag. See the [big warning on the `subprocess` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) about enabling the shell.

Comment: Ohhh I am such an idiot! I forgot the `shell=True`. I reverted to your (better) list solution and it works perfectly. Thanks for the quick response.